# Read Arabic text from text file using VBA and copying to Excel based on conditions

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

I have text file containing about 15,000 to 20,000 lines. These lines are either only in English or only in Arabic or combination of English and Arabic text. I need to write code in VBA to read each line and based on certain conditions, i need to copy the lines from text file to various Excel rows.

I have tried using FileSystemObject and other solutions but unable to read the code. While text with only English comes fine, however lines with Arabic text shows as Gibberish characters when pasted into Excel.

I am on PC with English settings. If i try to manually copy the text with Arabic characters and paste into Excel, it works perfectly fine.

Kindly let me know if you have done something similar in the past and possible approach on how this can be done using Excel VBA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use utf-8 encoding

Try something like this(read first 100 characters and past it to Cells A6):
You have to set reference to "Microsoft Active Data Objects 6.1 Library"

[image]

```
Sub UTF_8()
Dim obj As ADODB.Stream
Dim objFilePath As String
Dim objText As String

objFilePath = "C:\Arabic.txt"

Set obj = New ADODB.Stream

obj.Charset = "utf-8"


obj.Open
obj.LoadFromFile (objFilePath)


objText = obj.ReadText(100)

Range("A6").Value = objText

obj.Close
Set obj = Nothing
End Sub
```